# Stripes all over the desktop

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics

I am running ubuntu 11.10 , GNOME Shell. After some amount of memory consumption, my Ubuntu starts displaying stripes all over my desktop and also in the native application windows like empathy, nautilus etc.

My system information is as follows,

```
Memory: 2.9 GB
Processor: Intel Pentium Dual-core CPU E5200 @ 2.5 GHz
Graphics:  Intel® G33 x86/MMX/SSE2
```

Screen shots[image: desktop screenshot]:

[image: empathy screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thats weird.You could try to remove the desktop's visual effects system -> preferences -> Appearance ->Visual Effects-none which may remove those lines.I was having a similar issue on my ubuntu 11.10 and because i dont have the best graphics card ever that did help somehow.